# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I looked around `stackoverflow` and i see that this may have been asked before but I cannot wrap my head around the error.

I get this error :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' // first line
```

but my first line there is no error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Is this line part of a JS file?

Comment: This line is not the culprit...But your JS is....

Comment: @ gurvinder372  yes.

Comment: Somewhere your browser is expecting javascript but you're returning HTML. You should NEVER include DOCTYPE or any other HTML in an actual javascript file unless it's enclosed in a string like `document.write('<span>abc</span>');`.

Comment: Why are you putting HTML into your Javascript file?

Comment: this is not a valid JS, so it shouldn't be part of your JS file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `*.js` file you don't put a `<!doctype>` header on the first line.

Just start with your Javascript code or, at most, put a `"use strict";` there.

For example this is a valid JS file:

```
"use strict";

var x = 0;
```

But it is recommended to not poison the global space, so you really should do something more like this:

```
var LIB = (function () {
  "use strict";

  // your code goes here
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

As it actually says, the `DOCTYPE` declaration is for *HTML*, not for JavaScript.

Simply do not write it.